# Why is this line of code raising a syntax error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this line in a html.erb file:

```
<p> Share your unique link with as many people as you can. <b>The more people you refer, the sooner you will be invited to DreamStill.</b> Also, about every two weeks, <b>artists that have referred the greatest number of users will be featured in an email sent out to all DreamStill members!</b> To check up on how many users you have referred, simply enter your same email address (the one you used to sign up) into the signup form at <%= link to "the signup page.", "www.dreamstill.com" %></p>
```

Here's the error:

```
compile error
/app/app/views/user_mailer/email.html.erb:7: syntax error, unexpected '<'
<p> Share your unique link with...
 ^
/app/app/views/user_mailer/email.html.erb:7: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting kDO or '{' or '('
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`link to` should be `link_to`.

Answer (score 0):

use this `<%= link_to "the signup page.", "www.dreamstill.com" %>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<p> Share your unique link with as many people as you can. 
<b>The more people you refer, the sooner you will be invited to DreamStill.</b> 
**Also, about every two weeks, <b>artists that have referred the greatest number of users will be featured in an email sent out to all DreamStill members!</b>** 
To check up on how many users you have referred, simply enter your same email address (the one you used to sign up) into the signup form at <%= link to "the signup page.", "www.dreamstill.com" %>
</p>
```

You not have open  tag at line three